# name 'events' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, direct-line-botframework

Actually, I'm a beginner in python,I'm making a linebot and and I want to make a feature that can send back the ButtonsTemplate I made after detecting a keyword,I'm not sure if there are other bugs in my code,But when I run my code, it says event is not defined.I have written line_token and line_secret in the program, but I don't show them here.The last 7 lines are where the error occurs.Thanks. This is the full code that it wrote:

```
from linebot import LineBotApi, WebhookHandler

from linebot.models import PostbackAction,URIAction, MessageAction, TemplateSendMessage, ButtonsTemplate
line_bot_api = LineBotApi('')
handler = WebhookHandler('')
class Eatmodel():
def content(self):
template_message = TemplateSendMessage(
line_bot_api.push_message('U821215adb9a791364df34bdc4d5e96fb',

TemplateSendMessage(
alt_text='ButtonsTemplate',
template=ButtonsTemplate(
title='Eat點通-常見問題',
text='選擇問題',
actions=\[
MessageAction(
label='會員問題',
text='會員問題'
),
MessageAction(
label='食譜問題',
text='食譜問題'
),
MessageAction(
label='健康小知識',
text='健康小知識'
),
MessageAction(
label='廚房小知識',
text='廚房小知識'
)
\]
)
))
)
return template_message

for event in events:
if isinstance(event, MessageEvent):  # 如果有訊息事件
if event.message.text == "home":
line_bot_api.reply_message(  # 回復傳入的*your text*訊息文字
event.reply_token,
Eatmodel().content()
)
```

Comment: What do you expect `events` to be? Where should it come from?

Comment: My expectation is that when I type home in  line , it will automatically pass me the ButtonsTemplate I made.

Comment: There is no variable named `events` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem in this situation is that `events` is not defined, leading to the program being unable to run the loop. For more information on for loops, [Check out this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)